# mySQL/SQlite subtractive query

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I need a query in which it starts off by selecting the entire table, then there would be a few more querys that would remove entries from the first query. Ive accomplished this by using several querys and then comparing the results in my application. I was wondering if I can accomplish this in a single query.

*Algorithm*

1. Select All AccountIDs from table
2. Select AccountIDs from table where parameter1 = true
3. Remove those matches from the original query result
4. Select AccountIDs from table where parameter2 = true
5. Remove those matches from the remaining query result
6. and so on up to N parameters.

This would need to also be compatible with both mySQL and SQLite

Comment: post some data from the table

Comment: cant show the real data, as its sensitive but think of the table columns as |AccountID|parameter1|parameter2|parameter3|....|parameterN|

Comment: Basically, you want records for which `parameter1 = false AND ... AND parameterN = false`, right?

Comment: its not that simple, each query is independent of the other. It needs to start off selecting the entire table and start to remove entries as certain conditions are passed. Simply Saying Select Table where p1 = false and p2 = false .... and pN = false. Gives the wrong results. Because its looking for only the records that match all those conditions exactly.

Comment: It sounds like you just want results where all the Parameter fields are false? You will have to generate the SQL dynamically if there is no upper bound on the number of Parameter fields, but essentially it is just `SELECT AccountID FROM Account where parameter1 = FALSE AND parameter2 = FALSE AND etc.`

Edit:  I don't see how the combined SQL differs from subtracting them one by one

Comment: @rbedger OP wants to exclude records (e.g.) "WHERE parameter1 = FALSE AND parameter2 = TRUE".

Comment: because if its true then it would subtract the matches. But if its false it would not do anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for this:

```
SELECT AccountID FROM the_table
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT AccountID FROM the_table
    WHERE
        parameter1 = true OR
        ... OR
        parameterN = true ;
) AS not_included USING (AccountID)
WHERE not_included.AccountID IS NULL -- only items with no match in the "not_included" sub-query
```

The `not_included` subquery returns all items for which any parameter is set to `TRUE`. You actually want to exclude these records from your final result set.

Then LEFT-JOIN `the_table` (i.e. all items) to this sub-result. The `WHERE...IS NULL` clause excludes items present in `the_table` but not present in `not_included`.

Therefore only items which you do **not** want to exclude remain in the final result set.

Comment: That looks like that may be it, could you explain how it works so I can understand it better?

Comment: @MichaelTaylor3D I have added some details in my answer.

Comment: perfect! That is exactly what i was hoping for

Answer (score 2):

The most direct way to implement your algorithm is to use a [compound SELECT statement](http://sqlite.org/lang_select.html#compound):

```
SELECT AccountID FROM MyTable
EXCEPT
SELECT AccountID FROM MyTable WHERE parameter1 = 1
EXCEPT
SELECT AccountID FROM MyTable WHERE parameter2 = 1
```

However, this is also possible with a single `WHERE` expression:

```
SELECT AccountID
FROM MyTable
WHERE NOT (parameter1 = 1 OR
           parameter2 = 1 OR
           ...)
```

Comment: that looks like it could be another solution but EXCEPT operators of SQL are not supported in MySQL

Comment: Oh. My. God. This is so much more elegant... and certainly performs quicker than my convoluted solution.